# Encrypt password in a function does't work - postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have written a basic insertion function in postgres, it's aim is to insert data with an encrypted password , I have used Postgres native function **`PGP_SYS_ENCRYPT`** but am getting this error:

```
ERROR:  function pgp_sym_encrypt(text, unknown) does not exist
LINE 3:            PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(pass,'AES_KEY'),'0')
                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO users (username,email,password_,isDriver,login_status)  VALUES(usn,
                                                                            em,
                                            PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(pass,'AES_KEY'),'0')
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_users(character varying,character varying,text,character varying) line 5 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42883
```

**I don't know why it's like this, below is my function, what am I missing? :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_users(
    usn character varying,
    em character varying,
    pass text,
    isd character varying)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
declare
    total integer;

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO users (username,email,password_,isDriver,login_status)  VALUES(usn,
                                                                            em,
                                            PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(pass,'AES_KEY'),'0');
   RETURN 1;
END;

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.create_users(character varying, character varying, text, character varying)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a wild guess here would be: maybe you dont have it installed?..

```
db=# \sf pgp_sym_encrypt
ERROR:  function "pgp_sym_encrypt" does not exist
```

so you just

```
db=# create extension pgcrypto ;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

and:

```
db=# \sf pgp_sym_encrypt(text,text)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pgp_sym_encrypt(text, text)
 RETURNS bytea
 LANGUAGE c
 PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
AS '$libdir/pgcrypto', $function$pgp_sym_encrypt_text$function$
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but am still new in postgres, I just have MySQL experience , how can I run this query please?

Comment: run `create extension pgcrypto ;` and try your function again